# How to check for nil on an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rest-client

I do the following call to get a Ruby object, which returns data from Spotify's API:

`spotify_track = RSpotify::AudioFeatures.find('3RmAqYZZjiSyMV40hm6rDL')`

That returns:

```
#<RSpotify::AudioFeatures:0x00007fe0cc079b30 @acousticness=nil, @analysis_url="https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/3RmAqYZZjiSyMV40hm6rDL", @danceability=nil, @duration_ms=35361, @energy=nil, @instrumentalness=nil, @key=1, @liveness=nil, @loudness=-12.186, @mode=1, @speechiness=nil, @tempo=0, @time_signature=nil, @track_href="https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/3RmAqYZZjiSyMV40hm6rDL", @valence=nil, @external_urls=nil, @href=nil, @id="3RmAqYZZjiSyMV40hm6rDL", @type="audio_features", @uri="spotify:track:3RmAqYZZjiSyMV40hm6rDL">
```

When I try to get one of the attributes that's `nil`, I get a 404 error:

```
> spotify_track.acousticness
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):25
RestClient::NotFound (404 Not Found)
```

So, how can I check to see if an attribute is `nil` or not?

The usual things like `spotify_track.acousticness.present?`, `spotify_track.acousticness.blank?` and `spotify_track.try(:acousticness)` all return that same RestClient 404 error.

I'm using the [RSpotify](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify) gem, which makes use of the [REST Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem.

Comment: Are you saying you tried `spotify_track.present?` or `spotify_track.acousticness.present?`

Comment: @Btuman `spotify_track.acousticness.present?`

Comment: On a successful call, what does `spotify_track.acousticness.class` return?

Comment: @Btuman `=> Float`

Comment: and on an `.spotify_track.acousticness` that returns that 404?

Comment: Sorry, if I do `spotify_track.acousticness.class` when that attribute is `nil`, it returns 404. When `acousticness` has a value, then calling `.class` on it, returns `Float`.

Comment: Would you mind trying `spotify_track.respond_to?("acousticness")`

Comment: It returns `true`.

Comment: (that was actually a brain fart on my part, since it would always return true). Looking over the documentation, my only guess after going through their documentation/code is raw_response variable: `RSpotify.raw_response = true`, which should get you an object that you can play with nicer. Beyond that, I would consider opening an issue on their github page, as they seemed to have possibly implemented this incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

You can rescue and add some code to it,

```
rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => err
```

Refer [rest-client#response-callbacks-error-handling](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#response-callbacks-error-handling)